# Injecting Leakcanary RefWatcher via Dagger 2

Tags: android, dagger-2, leakcanary

I want to get RefWatcher object available throughout my activities and fragments so in my main application dagger module i did

```
@Provides
@AppScope
static RefWatcher provideRefWatcher(Application application) {
    return ((AppName) application).refWatcher;
}
```

and in my application class I declared

```
public class AppName extends DaggerApplication {

public RefWatcher refWatcher;
...
}
```

However when i inject into activity and use as

```
public class MainActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity {

@Inject
RefWatcher refWatcher;

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    refWatcher.watch(this);
}
```

Iam getting error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method
```

What is the correct way to inject this leakcanary refwatcher?

Answer (score 0):

Because refWathcer is null in this context. Try to get it like:

```
  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    refWatcher = LeakCanary.install(this);
  }
```

in your application class. But generally it's not a good idea using dagger in this case. After you installed LeakCanary you can use static LeakCanary.installedRefWatcher() to get refWatcher instance.